# Alignin div's like pinterest

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have searched for several things, but i just couldnt find the answer. Maybe you could help me out.

I want to align div elements like on Pinterest. Not all divs are the same height, but the gutter width stays the same. I am designing something and i would like to program it as well.

Here is an image of what I mean, for clarification: http://nl.tinypic.com/r/ekkkte/8

Graphicburger.com uses the same thing I mean to do. I just want to know how one would align his content like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one way to achieve this is by using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). I think this is what Pinterest actually uses for their layout. This also happens to work jQuery, if you are using that as well. If you are looking for more on the theory behind this, check out [this link](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-masonry-layout/)

The following is the demo code from the Masonry plugin/library link:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item w2">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  ...
</div>

<script src="/path/to/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
.item { width: 25%; }
.item.w2 { width: 50%; }
```

Javascript

```
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  columnWidth: 200,
  itemSelector: '.item'
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this might solve it for now gonna try as soon as I can.

Comment: Best of luck and have fun.

Answer (score 0):

i have answered a very similar post few days ago.. with sample code of html and css: [How to create grid position elements like in this image css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095914/how-to-create-grid-position-elements-like-in-this-image-css/27096556#27096556)

mind to take a look?